# $\Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}}_{\square}$ is not ccc

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, cardinals

Consider $\Bbb{Z}^{\Bbb{N}} \subseteq \Bbb{R}^{\Bbb{N}}$. The set $\Bbb{Z}^{\Bbb{N}}$ is uncountably infinite, since $|\Bbb{Z}^{\Bbb{N}}|$ = $|\Bbb{Z}|^{\Bbb{|N|}}$ = $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ > $2^{\aleph_0}$ = $\frak c$.

Now let $x = (x_1, x_2,....)\in \Bbb{Z^{\Bbb{N}}}$ a sequence with all integer values and the open set containing x of the form $U = B_{\epsilon}(x_1) \times B_{\epsilon}(x_2) \times ....$, where $\epsilon < 0.5$, so that the open set U around x contains no other all integer sequence. So we have uncountably many  disjoint open sets since ($\Bbb{Z}^{\Bbb{N}}$ is uncountable) and hence, the box topology is not ccc.
I'm wondering if I have the right idea and for some feedback. 
Thanks.

Comment: $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ is actually equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$. Apart from that, this is fine.

Comment: The open sets in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ are not of that form, so those are not open subsets of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Re-read the definition of the product topology.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Near the end of the question, the OP mentions that this is about the box topology, not the product topology.  That also seems to be the meaning of the subscript box in the title. It would, of course, have been much better and clearer to mention the box topology in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: What is "ccc" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: By now you probably know, but for the benefit of future readers, a topological space $X$ satisfies the [*countable chain condition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countable_chain_condition), or is *ccc*, iff every family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open sets in $X$ is countable.